# How do we get all folders containing images using MediaStore class (ANDROID)?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, file-manager

I have used MediaStore Class to get all the folders of images inside storage.
But the problem is it is showing the same folder as many times as the number of images in it.

```
    public void getImageDirProvider(){
    Uri uri= MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String projection[]={MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
    imageCursor=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);


    if (imageCursor!=null){
        while(imageCursor.moveToNext()){

            bucketName.add(imageCursor.getString(0));
            bucketId.add(imageCursor.getString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Here bucketName and bucketId are ArrayLists of String type.

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bucketName.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return bucketName.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    class Holder {
        ImageView iview;
        TextView tview;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder hold = new Holder();

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_adapter, parent, false);

            hold.tview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_adapter);
            hold.iview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        hold.tview.setText(getItem(position).toString());
        hold.iview.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Above is myCustomAdapter class extending BaseAdapter class.

Comment: @aribeiro. Yes, i have put a recyclerView in fragment which contains cardView. and the i have put onClickListener() on cardView to display first set of files using file handling in java. After that i am stuck, thinking how many more fragments will i use as i dont know the number of nested folders. and after how many folders i am going to get to the files...

Comment: How do I get all the folders having images inside using File handling? There has to be someway... to get images from both internal and sdcard storage...

Comment: @Prabh use content providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String projection[]={MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};`

you query for every available image hence returning cursor has as many records. So when you cycling over it you of course receive duplicate buckets.
Try to exclude images from query and query only for buckets available like

`String projection[]={MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID};`

if you still recieve duplicate values then try 
`String projection[] = {"DISTINCT " + MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID};`

Comment: it worked for me.Thank You. Is there a way to add a onItemClickListener() on listView and show the contents of the folder i.e images inside it using content provider.

Comment: first question easily answered by google actually (comment doesnt allow so much of code). second - i don't know, don't have too much experience in content providers

Comment: Is there another way of removing duplicate buckets ?, because i need to open them and access the files in it.So i need MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA column in it.